# ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed

Tags: linux, oracle, ora-00257

I am using Oracle 10g database server. It will not allow me to connect to my user showing this error:

> ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed

I found that this is the issue of space on database machine. How can I free space to get my database working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you speak to your DBA or whoever is the sysadmin for the machine.

The database has "frozen" operations that require redo until more space is available to write *archived* redo-log files to.

Comment: To write *archived* log files to, surely? The active redo log can't be switched because there are no log groups which have been archived, because log_archive_dest is full or otherwise unavailable, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error couple of times, it simply tells that archivelog space has exhausted and need to be freed.

```
> set oracled_sid=write_oracle_sid_here
> rman target sys/put_sys_password_here
> crosscheck archivelog all;
> delete noprompt expired archivelog all;
>exit;
```