# ORA-00257:archiver error

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, ora-00257

When I try connecting to my database, I get the following error.

> ORA-00257:archiver error. Connect internal only until freed.

Till yesterday, the database was pretty functional.

Any workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203367/ra-00257-archiver-error-connect-internal-only-until-freed)

Comment: @skaffman - Most likely, the source of the problem is different in 9i and 10g.  As a result, I believe they ought to be considered separate questions.

Comment: @Justin: I doubt it.  It's a pretty common Oracle error, the cause is usually the same - it's run out of log space.  Either way, it's a DBA problem, not a programming one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, can you

```
SQL> show parameter log_archive
```

- If `LOG_ARCHIVE_START` is FALSE,
  you'll want to set it to TRUE.
- If
  `LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST` points to an
  invalid directory, you'll want to
  change it to point to a valid
  directory.

Comment: I get no output when I run show parameter log_archive. I have a read-only permission to the db. Is that the reason why I get no output?

Comment: You'll need to be a DBA in order to fix the error.  If you just have a read-only account, you'll need to contact the DBA.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I will contact the DBA for this.

Answer (score 7):

**ORA-00257:archiver error** is occured when your archivelog reached the FRA limit. So you have to clear the archivelogs or you may increase the FRA limit.

To clear the archivelogs, connect to the command prompt and follow steps below:

```
rman target /
RMAN> delete archivelog all;
```

It will ask for confirmation and you have to give 'yes'.

Comment: At first, It can solve the problem immediately! But ... you are putting your DB into dangerous situation (have gap in archivelog). :(

Answer (score 3):

please note that you can only access SQL*PLUS if you login as 
sqlplus / as sysdba

Plus, I think the problem here is space quota for archiving
reaching its max limit.

So its best to clear the logs after making backup on a flash or something

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed. problem can be solved as following:
copy archivelog folder to a new destination and empty this directory.

The real problem is that online-backup limit increased what was set as n GB and that become full when you empty this archivelog folder then it will start working fine

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error couple of times, it simply tells that archivelog space has exhausted and need to be freed.

run cmd as administrator

```
> set oracled_sid=write_oracle_sid_here
> rman target sys/put_sys_password_here
> crosscheck archivelog all;
> delete noprompt expired archivelog all;
>exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Open rman or cmd, then type:
**connect target sys/live;** press enter
then:
**delete archivelog all;** press enter

Ask for confirmation press **y** then enter.
Your issue will be solved.